# How do I fix this zod error I am getting while deploying commands?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to deploy commands with discord.js v13, but I keep getting this error:

```
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "array",
    "received": "object",
    "path": [],
    "message": "Expected array, received object"
  }
]
```

I believe to have found where the error is in my code, I just don't know how to fix it. It is the part of the command where you add options to it. When I remove the `.setChoices()` function, it magically works, although I did follow exactly what [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#choices) said.

```
.addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('choice')
      .setDescription('What to do')
      .setRequired(true)
      .setChoices(
        { name: 'add', value: 'add' },
        { name: 'remove', value: 'remove' },
        { name: 'list', value: 'list' },
      ))
```

The problem is here, I just don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setChoices`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandStringOption?scrollTo=setChoices) requires an array, but [`addChoices`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandStringOption?scrollTo=addChoices) does not! so if you change `setChoices` to `addChoices` it'll work. Or wrap all the objects in an array, either should work.

Comment: I wrapped it in an array, and I got the same error, but three times.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your answer. Thanks for the help!